# Why is my data doubling up?

Tags: php

For some reason when I display results from my booking engine, it displays the results as follows:

Main Room
Main Room 2
Main Room
Main Room 2
Spare Room
Spare Room 2
Spare Room
Spare Room 2

It should be displaying as:

Main Room
Main Room 2
Spare Room
Spare Room 2

Hoping someone can see why it is doubling up from this.

```
<?php 

$array_rooms =null;

    if (get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'admin',true)) {
        $admin = true;
    } else {
        $admin = false;
        }

    ?>

<head>
    </head>

    <body id="results">

        <h1>Available <em>Rooms</em></h1>
      <table>

          <?php
          if($array_rooms != null){
              foreach($array_rooms as $key=>$room) { 


              $special = '';
              $roomRatePlanID = 119;
              if($key==0){ 
                    $room['desc'] = "Main Room"; 
                    $special = '&whp=1';
                    $roomRatePlanID = 68;
              }
              if($key==1){ 
                    $room['desc'] = "Main Room 2"; 
                    $special = '&whp=1';
                    $roomRatePlanID = 68;
              }
              if($key==2){ 
                    $room['desc'] = "Spare Room"; 
                    $special = '&whp=1';
                    $roomRatePlanID = 68;
              }
              if($key==3){ 
                    $room['desc'] = "Spare Room 2"; 
                    $special = '&whp=1';
                    $roomRatePlanID = 68;
              }
?>
          <tr<?php if (!get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'admin',true) && strpos($room['desc'],'Main Room') !== false) echo ' class="disabled"'; ?>>
              <td>
                  <div>
                      <h2><a href="/rooms/" target="_blank"><?php echo $room['desc'] ." " . $room['available'] ;?></a></h2>
                      <div><?php
                        if ($room['desc'] == "Main Room"){
                            echo "<strong>Rate: $89.00</strong>';
                        }elseif(($room['desc'] == "Main Room 2")){
                            echo "<strong>$79.00</strong>";
                        } else{
                            if ($admin)
                                $netrate = number_format($room['rates'][119],2);
                            else
                                $netrate = number_format($room['rates'][20] - ($room['rates'][20] / 100 * get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'package',true)),2);

                            echo "Customer Rate: <strong>$".number_format($room['rates'][20],2).'</strong> / Net Rate: <strong>$'.$netrate.'</strong>';
                        }?></div>
                      <div><a href="/book/summary?roomTypeCode=<?php echo $room['roomTypeCode'] . $special;?>">Book</a></div>
                      </div>
              </td>
          </tr>

    <tr<?php if (!get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'admin',true) && strpos($room['desc'],'Main Room') !== false) echo ' class="disabled"'; ?>>
                  <td>
                      <div>
                          <h2><a href="/rooms/" target="_blank"><?php echo $room['desc'] ." " . $room['available'] ;?></a></h2>
                          <div><?php
                            if ($room['desc'] == "Spare Room"){
                                echo "<strong>Rate: $59.00</strong>';
                            }elseif(($room['desc'] == "Spare Room 2")){
                                echo "<strong>$49.00</strong>";
                            } else{
                                if ($admin)
                                    $netrate = number_format($room['rates'][119],2);
                                else
                                    $netrate = number_format($room['rates'][21] - ($room['rates'][21] / 100 * get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'package',true)),2);

                                echo "Customer Rate: <strong>$".number_format($room['rates'][20],2).'</strong> / Net Rate: <strong>$'.$netrate.'</strong>';
                            }?></div>
                          <div><a href="/book/summary?roomTypeCode=<?php echo $room['roomTypeCode'] . $special;?>">Book</a></div>
                          </div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          <?php } }else{ echo 'no results'; }?>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: that's not the code you are using to produce the results shown its full of syntax errors

Comment: That's obviously not the complete code, but that is the bit that is being duplicated. If you see errors with the above please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @Dave mainly this: `echo "<strong>Rate: $59.00</strong>';` ... you have that twice.

Comment: @ m.buettner: Updated code m.buettner, thank you.

Comment: still with errors therefore not actully what you are using. in addition to that var_dump($array_rooms) would help

Comment: I had only left out things that were irrelevant such as `require_once './book/bookingengine.php';`

Comment: HUGE output when dumping that array - want a pastebin?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see this whole thing is executed for every single `$room`. Both `h2`s are printed in every case. And both of them `echo $room['desc']`, which seems to contain the strings that you only want to have once. So I guess you simply wrap your first `<tr>...</tr>` in `if ($room[desc] == "Main Room" || $room[desc] == "Main Room 2"):` ... `endif;`. And the second one in the same thing with `Spare Room`. However, I have no idea what you want to do, if your description is none of those four values. Right now it would make sense that both `<tr>`s would be printed, since the `else` conditions inside the `<div>`s seem to be different.

Comment: Thanks m.buettner - If those rooms are available, which they are, and logged in as admin which it is, it should display them. Just displays twice for each room. If I wrap them with the `||` I then have to display different prices for each within that statement depending on which room it is...

Comment: Sorry, this question is really lacking context. It's hard to help you like this. You just dropped in a very cut-down version of what you see and dumped some part of your code (which would even throw loads of errors, due to unmatched quotes). Please tell us what you are actually trying to achieve and what those variables represent. Then maybe, someone can help you.

Comment: No problem - I'll update the question in a couple of minutes. Just thought it may be more difficult if someone that is willing to help, such as yourself, would have to rummage through a tonne of code. Thanks again

Comment: you should be able to remove most of the code and show the minimum that has\illustrates the error. Which you should already have done for debugging anyway

Comment: @Dagon: Updated code, thank you. I'll begin debugging by removing some code as well, as per your suggestion :)

Comment: @Dave the main point of my comment was not to make you dump even more code, but to explain what you are trying to accomplish ;)